# Warning in Arduino compiler: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino

I'm using a string in various places so I made it a variable to reuse - like this:

```
String strBoardName = "XY32";
```

Unfortunately in the following line, it doesn't work:

```
ArduinoOTA.setHostname(strBoardName); // give a name to our module
```

and gives me the error:

> note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'String' to 'const char*'
> no matching function for call to 'ArduinoOTAClass::setHostname(String&)'

So, I have been forced to declare another variable to use on this line, thusly:

```
char* BoardName = "XY32";
```

and use it like:

```
ArduinoOTA.setHostname(BoardName); // give a name to our module
```

which was working, but I would really like to have to use only one variable.

Workarounds are available ([On the Arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=372563.0) and [On SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421213/deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-wwrite-strings-error-in) ), but don't really address my problem.

Also, although this was working earlier, I upgraded from Arduino 1.6.5 to Arduino 1.8.13 and have an additional issue.  I get this message:

> warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings] char* BoardName = "XY32";

pointing to the line:

```
char* BoardName = "XY32";
```

What is the right way to use this variable so it is correct (i.e. no warnings or error messages) and I can use a single variable instead of two of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `char* BoardName = "XY32";` is not how you define a C string!

use

`char BoardName[] = "XY32";`

`String strBoardName = "XY32";` creates a String.

ArduinoOTA.setHostname() expects a const char pointer.

So intead of

```
ArduinoOTA.setHostname(strBoardName);
```

do this

```
ArduinoOTA.setHostname(strBoardName.c_str());
```

See https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/c_str/

Comment: Thanx!  That worked!  I have always been confused about strings in C.  And it's been a while, so I've forgotten what I learned. :-)

Comment: c style strings are \0 terminated char arrays. that's why you ususally address them through a char pointer. it points to the first character of that string and ends at the null character. so you don't have to give a length. but you don't create them as a char pointer as you attempted

Comment: `const char* BoardName = "XY32";` would work

Comment: @Piglet yes, it's coming back now.  Each character has a pointer to the next character or something like that.  I'll have to crack those C books again!